# How to get current item check/uncheked in slick grid event onSelectedRowsChanged

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

Is there any way to get the current row while selecting the row in a slick grid?
also how to identify that the checkbox state using this?

I am using checkbox selection plugin of a slick grid. and binding a subscribe event of row selection like

```
grid.onSelectedRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                        // args.rows : Return the selected rows
                        // Code here
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var rtn = getActiveCell();` to give `rtn.row`, `rtn.cell` and `rtn.grid`.
`grid.getSelectedRows()` will tell you the row selections as an array of row indexes. If the active row is in that array, then the checkbox is ticked.

Comment: var rtn = getActiveCell(); this method returns the valid active cell if a user clicks on that row and then select a checkbox. If a user clicks on checkbox then that method not return the exact active cell for more info check this [link]https://www.screencast.com/t/5HwZLbiImV) . as you can see in this video first I have click on the row and then select checkbox will return me the right value. but if I have click on the checkbox first then the active cell not return the right value.

Comment: With the current checkbox-row-select example, there is no relationship between the 'active' row and clicking the checkbox to select the row. 'Active' row is a completely separate concept to 'selected' row. Why do you need it? Selection of the checked/unchecked row could be added to the ```slick.checkboxselectcolumn.js``` plugin.

Comment: (i mean you could mod the plugin so that when selecting or deselecting a row, it becomes the *active* row, if that's what you want)